# How can I add two complex statements in a correct way for queryset.filter in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am filtering my Article viewset on Django. The code below works fine,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets,filters
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics
from url_filter.integrations.drf import DjangoFilterBackend

class ArticleFilterBackEnd(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            article__author__followers__author=request.user
        )
```

But I also want to use `queryset.exclude()` inside the same loop and filter where
`article__author__followers__issilent= True`

when statement is in same loop with `request.user` so it does not point out to any other followers loop.

How can I do it?

Comment: It;s unclear what you mean with "loop"? Do you just mean to chain and combine these conditions like `queryset.filter(article__author__followers__author=request.user).exclude(article__author__followers__issilent= True)`?

Comment: "Loop" means that `article__author__followers` is same on both querysets and does not point to different followers.Yes, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` instead of `exclude`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets,filters
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics
from url_filter.integrations.drf import DjangoFilterBackend

class ArticleFilterBackEnd(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
       return queryset.filter(article__author__followers__author=request.user, article__author__followers__issilent=False)
```